# Finding a group isomorphic to ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

let $J$ be an ideal of $F[x]$ such that $J$ contains every polynomial of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with constant term a multiple of 4. Im looking for a ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$, with proof.

I was thinking that maybe $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong \mathbb{Z}_4[x]$,

I started by defining a homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, where $\phi(a(x)) = \overline{a(x)}$ for any $a(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Just a small thing - in the title, you ask about a group isomorphic to the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but that statement doesn't make sense. In the body you stated it correctly, though

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the set of all polynomial with $a_0$ even is exactly the ideal $(2,x)\subset \Bbb Z[x]$. Now you can see that $\Bbb Z[x] /(2,x)\cong \Bbb Z_2[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb Z_2$ that is a field, so $(2,x)$ is maximal and it must be $J=(2,x)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have $f+J=g+J$ if and only if the free coefficient of $f-g$ is even, which happens if and only if the free coefficients of $f,g$ are equal mod $2$. So $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$ contains just two elements (the class of polynomials with even free coefficient and the class of polynomials with odd free coefficient) and this should make it clear that the ring you are looking for is $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Formally, define a map $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z_2}$ by $\varphi(\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i)=a_0$ (mod $2$). It is easy to see that $\varphi$ is a surjective homomorphism of rings and its kernel is exactly $J$. Now apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You are, in fact, quite close. Consider the function $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$, defined by $\phi(p(x)) \mapsto \overline{a_0} \operatorname{(mod} 2)$.

I) $\phi$ is a homomorphism:

If $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $p(x) = a_0 + ... + a_nx^n$ and $q(x) = b_0 + ... + b_m x^m$, which means the independent term of $(p + q)(x)$ is $(a_0 + b_0)$, and the independent term of $(pq)(x)$ is $a_0b_0$. Therefore, $\phi(p + q) = \overline{(a_0 + b_0)} = \overline{a_0} + \overline{b_0} = \phi(p) + \phi(q)$ and $\phi(pq) = \overline{a_0b_0} = \overline{a_0}\overline{b_0} = \phi(p)\phi(q)$.

II) $\phi$ is clearly surjective

III) $\phi$ has the kernel:

$\operatorname{ker}\phi = \{p \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : \phi(p) = \overline{0}\} = \{p \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : a_0 = \overline{0} \operatorname{(mod}2)\} = J$

Using the First Homomorphism Theorem, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot! To expand on II) surjectivity, I'm looking to formalize this point so would this be a valid proof: since every element $a\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ is $\in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of the form $f(x) = a$ thus $\phi(f(x)) = a_0$?

Comment: No problem! I'll elaborate: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has only two elements, namely $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$. The polynomial $p(x) = 0$ gets sent to $\overline{0}$, and the polynomial $q(x) = 1$ gets sent to $\overline{1}$. Therefore, we have covered the entirety of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Your explanation would be perfect, if it weren't for a simple detail (which I am not quite sure about, and hence avoid using): you imply $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is contained in $\mathbb{Z}$, and I don't think you can say that. But the idea was perfect!

Comment: got it thank you!